# how to run shell scripts in a docker instance on a azure pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I have a working azure pipeline, something like this:

```
trigger: none

jobs:
- job: RunTest
  workspace:
    clean: all
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Login to ACR
    inputs:
      command: login
      containerRegistry: my-acr
  - script: |
      docker run my-registry.azurecr.io/somerepo/rnd-hello:latest
```

How to run now multiple shell scripts on the docker image?
For example, how to do the following now :

- cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Bbuild;
- cmake --build build --config Release
- ... run some shell scripts already included in the docker image

My Problems are :
The Azure Container Instance does not support parameters like docker -it and --rm.
And if I use docker exec, I think it will start in every line a new instance and I can not use the results of the previous line.

Any Ideas on how to run multiple shell scripts on one instance of a docker image in a azure pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I use docker exec, I think it will start in every line a new instance and I can not use the results of the previous line.

For this question, in fact, the `docker exec` command does not start a new instance of the container. The confusion might arise from the fact that each `docker exec` command starts a new shell session in the running container, and these sessions are independent of each other. If you have a Docker container already running, you can use `docker exec` to run commands in that same container.  If you are modifying data that are stored on the container, those changes will persist between `docker exec` commands, as they all interact with the same container.

You can also write your commands in a `script.sh` file and run the script inside the running Docker container, when you have multiple commands that need to be run in sequence or depend on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating the info of @Miao Tian-MSFT I ended with the following solution:

```
jobs:
- job: RunTest
  workspace:
    clean: all
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Login to ACR
    inputs:
      command: login
      containerRegistry: my-acr
  - script: |
      docker run --name=mycontainer my-registry.azurecr.io/somerepo/rnd-hello:latest 
      docker exec mycontainer bash -c 'cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Bbuild;'
      docker exec mycontainer bash -c 'cmake --build build --config Release'
      docker exec mycontainer bash -c './scripts/run_tests.sh'
      docker cp mycontainer:/app/build $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```